# Angular Typescript Display Variables in View from Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to display some values that might exist in a JSON response. If they don't exist, they should be set to 0.

My switch statement looks like inside my component typescript looks like:

```
this.failures = obj.failures;
this.subsystemFailure = new SubsystemFailure();

        for(let i=0;i<this.failures.length; i++){
              switch(this.failures[i].appName) {
                case "a": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.a = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case  "b": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.b = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case  "c": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.c = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case  "d": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.d = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case "e": 
                this.subsystemFailure.e = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case "f": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.f = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;              
                case "g": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.g = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                case "h": 
                  this.subsystemFailure.h = this.failures.appFailures;
                  break;
                } 

            }
```

My class ts file looks like:

```
export class SubsystemFailure {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d: number;
  e: number;
  f: number;
  g: number;
  h: number;

  constructor(){
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 0;
    this.c = 0;
    this.d = 0;
    this.e = 0;
    this.f = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.h = 0;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to display the data in the view, where if there is no value, if will display as zero:

```
<li>
  <div class="title">A</div>
    <div class="value">
      <strong>{{subsystemFailure.a}}</strong>
    </div>
  <div>
</li>
```

Currently, the subsystemFailure.a (it's the first) variable is coming back as undefined. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: where's your variable "A"? I just see variable "a".

Comment: @tin sorry, it is subsystemFailure.a

Comment: can you show me more? From what you showed me, nothing seems to be wrong. One thing I can think is `this.failures.appFailures` value has `underfined` value. So it's overwriting `underfined` to the default `0`.

Comment: I just noticed `this.failures` is an array. So `this.failures.appFailures` may be wrong without index. Change them to `this.failures[i].appFailures`.

Comment: @tin so if failures.appName doesn't exist, it automatically gets a value of 0. That parts seems to be working. For instance, the json result shows that "a" has a value of 2, but is being displayed as undefined in the console; All others are showing up as 0 in the view.

Comment: put `console.log(this.failures.appFailures)` in every case statement and see what the output is

Comment: @StephenRoss [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrpwzh) is a StackBlitz I started for you. Obviously it doesn't work. Try cleaning it up and working in that environment and post a link in the question body for people to try to help. GL!

Comment: so I ended up refactoring everything so that it looks like:  
         
`this.failures = obj.failures;
 this.subsystemFailure = new SubsystemFailure(); if(obj.failureFlag) {
            for (let app of this.failures) {
              this.subsystemFailure[app.appName] = app.appNoOfFailures || 0;
            }
          }`

Comment: @Tin so I do have it doing what I need it to... however Angular is complaining that `this.failures` cannot be an array, even though it is an array of object.

Comment: I'd be happy to help if you tell me more about what is that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up refactoring the code as such:

```
  this.subsystemFailure = new SubsystemFailure();

  if(this.failureFlag) {
    for (let app of json.failures) {
      this.subsystemFailure[app.appName] = app.appNoOfFailures || 0;
    }
   }
```

Instead of a switch statement, this iterates over the response and assigns the value associated with `appName`, or a value of 0 if there isn't an `appName` in the response.